# How to explain sudden increase in Daily Sessions and decrease in Queries?

Tags: analytics, dialogflow-es, actions-on-google

Our educational Action suddenly had Daily Sessions **increased** from 28 to 208 (**8 times** more).

Also the Queries per session **decreased** from 6.4 to 1.5 (4 times less).

This happened on 6/20/2019.

Here's a graph from Analytics page in DialogFlow console:

[image: graph from Analytics page in DialogFlow console]

There were no changes to our Action and no recent marketing has been done.

How to find out what caused these **dramatic** changes?

Comment: Check for `Discovery` section under `Analytics`. Google is giving suggestions based on your intent keyword phrases. I have not shared my action with anyone still it has 900 conversation in just a week.

Comment: I see "Your app had no implicit discoveries for the selected time period" when you go to Discovery section under Analytics.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out Google Health Checks (about 8 per hour) started to be included in session count.